# Django Activity Stream vs Feedly

Tags: feedly, django-activity-stream, stream-framework

We are building django based REST APIs, where one of the features is News feed. After some googling I could see the following 2 options:

- [Django Activity Stream](https://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (will have to use Redis on top of this)
- [Stream Framework](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Framework) (previously called Feedly)

My question is, which one will be more appropriate considering development time and scalability ?

Comment: Did you pick one of these two?  What was your experience?  Did you ever come across any other candidate frameworks?

Comment: @MartinBayly I'm using Stream Framework: http://getstream.io/
It's really easy to use and has enough free requests to try out in developement

Comment: Hi @SaurabhVerma I am using stream-sjango too but could not able to configure it properly. I am getting `StreamApiException:GetStreamAPI404`. Could you please help me to configure stream-django?